# How to deploy/host a wordpress(.org) website built locally to a domain bought with siteground

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

Please help. I have a wordpress folder on my local and will the client bought the domain on siteground, its my first time using wordpress and siteground, How do I host the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use all in one migration plugin to do this job , in order to do , first install WordPress in server. Export file from localhost using this plugin , and importing this .wpress file into your server using this all in one migration plugin , link to download all in one migration here

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

File size limit : < 600mb